# Remove all except certain folders from git history

Tags: git

I have a complex git repo from which I would like to delete **ALL** files and history except for two folders, let's say:

```
foo/a
bar/x/y
```

While `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` would let me select one folder, and make that the new root, it doesn't seem to give me any option for selecting two directories, and preserving their placement.

`git filter-branch --tree-filter` or `--index-filter` seem like it will let me iterate through every commit in history, where I can use `git rm` on an unwanted folder.

I cannot seem to find any working way to get these commands to just preserve the two folders I desire while clearing **everything** else.

Thanks!

Comment: Solution was:
`git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | grep -vE "foo/a/|bar/x/y/" | xargs git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch'`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633033/remove-history-for-everything-except-a-list-of-files-using-git-filter-branch

Comment: `git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | grep -vE "foo/a/|bar/x/y/" | xargs git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch'` was terminating almost immediately, due to `git rm` not receiving any files to delete from `grep` for some commits.              The trick is to give it one non-existing file always to try to delete: `git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | grep -vE "foo/a/|bar/x/y/" | xargs git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch xxxxxxxxx'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct: a tree filter or an index filter would be the way to do this with `git filter-branch`.

The tree filter is easier, but much slower (easily 10 to 100 times slower).  The way a tree filter works is that your supplied command is run in a temporary directory that contains all, and only, the files that were present in the original (now being copied) commit.  Any files your command leaves behind, remain in the copied commit.  Any files your command creates in the temporary directory, are also in the copied commit.  (You may create or remove directories within the temporary directory with no effect either way, since Git stores only the files.)  Hence, to remove everything *except* A and B, write a command that removes every file that is in something other than either A or B:

```
find . -name A -prune -o -name B -prune -o -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

for instance.

The index filter is harder, but faster because Git does not have to copy all the files out to a file tree and then re-scan the file tree to build a new index, in order to copy the original commit.  Instead, it provides only an index, which you can then manipulate with commands like `git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch` for instance, or `git update-index` for the most general case.  But, now the only tools you have are those in Git that manipulate the index.  There is no fancy Unix `find` command.

You do, of course, have `git ls-files`, which reads out the current contents of the index.  Hence you can write a program in whatever language you like (I would use Python first here, probably, others might start with Perl) that in essence does:

```
for (all files in the index)
    if (file name starts with 'A/' or 'B/')
        do nothing
    else
        add to removal list
invoke "git rm --cached" on paths in removal list
```

If you are willing to trust that no file name has an embedded newline, the above can be done in regular shell as:

```
git ls-files | IFS=$'\n' while read path; do
    case "$path" in A/*|B/*) continue;; esac
    git rm --cached "$path"
done
```

which is not terribly efficient (one `git rm --cached` per path!) but should work "out of the box" as an `--index-filter`.

(Untested, but probably works and should be significantly more efficient: pipe `git ls-files` output through `grep -v` to remove desired files, and pipe `grep` output into `git update-index --force-remove --stdin`.  This still assumes no newlines in path names.)

Comment: Thanks @torek! Not being familiar with `find` I had to deconstruct it a bit, until I got it working but it would take about an hour.

I found a good solution with:
`git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | grep -vE "foo/a/|bar/x/y/" | xargs git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch'` although one iteration exceeded the number of arguments I could pipe to `xargs`.

I solved this by doing a first pass to remove whole large folders first, using `git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch c/ d/ e/' HEAD`

Answer (score 2):

For *files*, I've done this with `git fast-export`. But I'm not sure that would work recurseively on directories. So I'd suggest using a combination of `git fast-export` and `find`.

```
git fast-export HEAD -- `find foo/a bar/x/y -type f` >../myfiles.fi
```

Then create a new repo, and import the streams.

```
 git init
 git fast-import <../myfiles.fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A newer and much better way to achieve this is to use `filter-repo`.

```
git filter-repo --path foo/a --path bar/x/y
```

`filter-branch` is now recommended against in its docs (version 2.30.0 here):

> WARNING
>
> `git filter-branch` has a plethora of pitfalls that can produce
> non-obvious manglings of the intended history rewrite (and can leave
> you with little time to
> investigate such problems since it has such abysmal performance).
> These safety and performance issues cannot be backward
> compatibly fixed and as such, its use is not
> recommended. Please use an alternative history filtering tool such as
> `git filter-repo[1]`. If you still need to use `git filter-branch`, please carefully read the
> section called "SAFETY" (and the section called "PERFORMANCE") to learn
> about the land mines of filter-branch, and then vigilantly
> avoid as many of the hazards listed there as reasonably possible.

Answer (score 0):

After many failed attempts at this myself, I finally got it figured out with `git filter-repo` thanks to @Ken's answer here as well as method 3 here: https://www.baeldung.com/git-remove-file-commit-history#using-git-filter-repo

Other answers did not work right for me, or were just plain confusing. In particular, none of the `filter-branch` options worked for me.

```
git clone <remoteA-URL>
cd <repo>

# If you want to push results to a new repo, uncomment these two lines:
#git remote rm origin
#git remote add origin <remoteB-URL>

# not sure this is necessary, but the resource above recommends it
git filter-repo --analyze

# Rewrite the commit history of the repo,
# recalculating hashes etc, removing all files, commits,
# and even partial commit-data not associated w/ the listed dirs
git filter-repo --force --path keepDir0 --path keepDir1
git push origin <branch>
```

> Note that `git filter-repo` is preferred to `git filter-branch` as per the official git documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch