# Remove history for everything except a list of files using git filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to move some files between two git repositories `repo1` and `repo2`. I have a short list of files I'd like to move (preserving history).

Three files to move from `repo1`:

```
libraryname/file1
libraryname/file2
tests/libraryname/file3
```

There are other files in `libraryname/` and `tests/libraryname/`. There are other folders in `/` and `tests/`

My plan is to checkout `repo1`, then modify the history tree until it only contains history for the files I'm interested in. Then checkout `repo2`, and merge in the output of the previous operation. It seems like `git filter-branch` is the right tool for the first step.

So far I've tried `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached <FILES>'`
Where `<FILES>` lists every unwanted whole folder or file.

But this leaves a lot of folders which no longer exist at `HEAD`, but have existed at some point in this repositories lifetime. It seems quite tedious to figure out everything that has existed in the history of this repo - there must be a better way

How do I end up with a git commit tree which only includes these three files?
Is there a better way then I'm suggesting?
Or, is there a way to remove traces of all files which don't currently exist at `HEAD`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said it leaves behind folders; I assume you mean it leaves behind files *in* those folders (because git doesn't preserve empty folders)...

It seems like you might want to take the approach of clearing the index and then re-adding the entries you want.

```
git filter-branch ...
    --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached * && git reset $GIT_COMMIT -- libraryname/file1 libraryname/file2 tests/libraryname/file3
    ...
```

Since you're thinning out the content so much, don't forget that you may want to include a `--prune-empty` option

Comment: This worked for me where `git checkout $GIT_COMMIT <path>` failed (for commits in which `<path>` does not exist). Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), [**`git filter-branch` is deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

The equivalent would be, using [**`newren/git-filter-repo`**](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), and its [example section](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

> If you have a long list of files, directories, globs, or regular expressions to filter on, you can stick them in a file and use `--paths-from-file`; for example, with a file named `stuff-i-want.txt` with contents of

```
README.md
guides/
tools/releases
glob:*.py
regex:^.*/.*/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.txt$
tools/==>scripts/
regex:(.*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.text$==>\2/\1/\3.txt
```

> then you could run

```
git filter-repo --paths-from-file stuff-i-want.txt
```

In your case, `stuff-i-want.txt` would be:

```
libraryname/file1
libraryname/file2
tests/libraryname/file3
```

---

As [kubanczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122727/kubanczyk) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633033/remove-history-for-everything-except-a-list-of-files-using-git-filter-branch/58251984?noredirect=1#comment109726938_58251984):

> Works well on Ubuntu 20.04, you can just `pip3 install git-filter-repo` since it's stdlib-only and doesn't install any dependencies.
>
> On Ubuntu 18 it's incompatible with distro's git version, but it's easy to enough to run it on a `docker run -ti ubuntu:20.04`

Comment: Nice tool! Works well on Ubuntu 20.04, you can just `pip3 install git-filter-repo` since it's stdlib-only and doesn't install any dependencies. On Ubuntu 18 it's incompatible with distro's git version, but it's easy to enough to run it on a `docker run -ti ubuntu:20.04`

Comment: @kubanczyk THank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whitelist-based approach which might be faster (because it only needs to compare whole lines of pre-sorted lists) and easier if a large number of files is involved.

1. Create a sorted list of all files in all commits of your branch:

   `$ export LC_COLLATE=C whitelist="$(mktemp)" && git log --name-status | sed 's/^[A-Z][[:space:]]\{1,\}//; t; d' | sort -u > "$whitelist"`
2. Edit that list with your favorite text editor and remove all files which are not of interest for keeping, i. e. create a white list of files to keep.

   `$ "$EDITOR" -- "$whitelist" # remove from list what you don't want to keep`
3. Perform the actual filter operation:

   `$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git ls-files -c | sort | comm -23 -- - "$whitelist" | while IFS= read -r f; do git rm --cached -- "$f"; done' --prune-empty`
4. Remove the white list once the filter operation worked without problems.

   `$ rm -- "$whitelist" && unset LC_COLLATE whitelist`